# undefined reference to `log@GLIBC_2.29' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: 18.04, cross-compilation

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --includedir=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```

**Should upgrade aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc to  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-9? I donot want update the ubuntu version. Is there a way to upgrade aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc separately?**